# 950XL Double tap wake up

Tags: windows-10-mobile, lumia-950-xl

I have the 950XL, and I can't seem to find how to configure the phone to wake up after a double tap. This worked on my lumia 1520, but does not appear to be the  default configuration in Windows 10.  I'm hoping they have not dropped the feature!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Windows 10 Creators Update (2017-06): 
Settings -> Peronalisation -> Lock Screen: "Double-tap to wake up phone"

Answer (score 5):

Double-tap to wake is currently not supported on the Lumia 950 or 950 XL. It's speculated that support will be added at a later date, but as far as I know no official statements have been made.

For more information, see [Does my Lumia support double tap to wake up?](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/mobile/support/faq/?action=singleTopic&topic=FA144547)

Comment: It should be coming, from a Microsft employee :
https://twitter.com/Nawzil10/status/660429508923658240

We can notice that the app he's mentionning "Gestures and touch" is visible in the "manage background running apps" section in the battery settings. I'm guessing the setting is hidden at the moment, meaning we can't enable it

Comment: There is a Microsoft Feedback App.  Make sure to download and add the feedback...  This will let them know directly and it can be voted on!!!

Answer (score 2):

Double-tap to wake is now supported on the Lumia 950 and 950 XL.

Go to "Settings -> Extras -> Touch" then slide "Wake up the phone when I double-tap on the screen" to "on".  Exiting the settings page will then prompt you to restart the phone for the new setting to take effect.

Comment: As per @kamrca's answer, this is no longer needed on Creators Update. You can still use it, but the built-in (non-"Extras") approach does not require a reboot.